# Which is faster: toggle display of two divs, or switch background-image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got 36 png keyframes which I want to display one by one. I see two generic ways of doing this: have 36 `div` blocks with different `background-image` which is toggled by `display` property, or have single `div` block and set different `background-image` on it. I wonder which way is faster.

Comment: Have you tested? That would seem the simplest way to test...no?

Comment: Use a gif? Or animated png?

Comment: @Paulie_D both ways looks momentary. By 'faster' i mean more effective on resource useage

Comment: if you need to know the answer, test, on as many browsers as you can - you may find some browsers are better one way, and other browsers are better the other - good luck with your benchmarking

Comment: You could merge all the png images into one sprite image and then just cycle through them using background-position.

Comment: @OllieMurphy, i know i may, question is about perfomance

Answer (score 0):

Toggling the visibility means your images were already downloaded from server (unless you toggle too quickly after load of course). Changing the background will make a new request until you toggled through all.

Unless you can use a sprite and change the background position.

I don't think there's that much difference in performance between changing display or background, it's still just changing some css.